# custom seekbar/scrubber on a media player UWP

Tags: multithreading, win-universal-app, seekbar

So I'm coding a music player and don't want to use their defualt mediaplayer control panel.

I have a slider object (SeekBar) and I know I can update it to display the postion i am in a current song as such:

```
SeekBar.Value = (int)PlayMusic.Position.TotalMilliseconds;
```

So when I call the above the bar move to the exact position I need it to be

So how can I start a thread (async method?) that calls a function that loops the above every millisecond. I'm pretty new and have been trying this for a while.

Comment: I think you should try to use binding for that. I've already posted [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29030817/2681948), maybe it will help.

Comment: Why create it from start when you can just edit the template of MediaTransportControls?